# Optional query strings in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to handle these requests with the same controller action:

1. `localhost:52000/api/messages`
2. `localhost:52000/api/messages?page=1`
3. `localhost:52000/api/messages?date=2019/29/11&page=1`

I made a controller action as following:

```
[Route("api/messages")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getMessage(DateTime? date, int? page)
```

But this only works if the query string value is null, not if the actual query is null.

- Working: `localhost:52000/api/messages?date=&page=`
- Not working (It doesn't find the action): `localhost:52000/api/messages`

> How can I make every `api/messages` request be handled by the
>   `getMessage()` action?

Thanks!

Comment: set default value for both the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
[Route("api/messages")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getMessage(DateTime? date = null, int? page = null)
```